# Jquery drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Does anyone know of a plugin that can help me with a dropdown menu like this site 
http://www.ebuyer.com/
when its hovered over a div appears with categories headers and  side by side categories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it qualifies as a plug-in, since you'll need to write your own CSS/JavaScript, but the techniques described [here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/) seem similar to what you are needing.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

There are many plugins that can do things similar.
Have a look at this page that lists several plugins and tutorials: [here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)